# Need a cheap embedded linux board that has WiFi access point and USB2.0

Tags: usb, wifi, linux, host

I need a small embedded Linux board that has the following:

1. On board WiFi access point
2. USB 2.0 high-speed HOST.
3. Under $100, preferably under $70 or around $50

Basically I need to send real-time video or multimedia data/files received at the USB HOST, over the WiFi access point very fast.

I saw this one board that seems be a good one, MiniEMBWiFi

http://robosavvy.com/store/advanced_search_result.php?keywords=miniembwifi

I'm in USA, but that board seems to be in the UK, dont know if UK Wifi will work in USA??

Anybody knows of any other Linux boards out there that can fill these requirements?

Thanks

Comment: 2.4GHz Wifi is international, up to and including channel 11. See [Wiki for more details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels)

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic. You are trying to buy a specialized computer, [su] might already have answers available.

Answer (score 2):

I've had some success with routers running OpenWRT as embedded platforms. My router of choice at the moment is TP-Link's TL-703N. This is a Chinese device shipped with a Chinese web GUI but there are [great instructions on the OpenWRT wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr703n) for installing OpenWRT on the device.

The device is sold as a travel router for 3G dongles. It doesn't have 3G built in but does have 802.11n WIFI, ethernet and USB 2.0. Its main feature is price, I got mine from eBay for £17 (about US$25).

I wrote up a wee post on the device on my hackerspace's blog, [here](http://edinburghhacklab.com/2012/05/raspberry-pi-alternative/).

It's a nice, small, embedded platform, and it's possible to tack some wires on the board for a hardware serial port.